# CSS and HTML - How to make divs not overlap?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I'm trying to make a photo gallery in the middle of my screen using percentages, the image ends up in the center and function ok with the jquery to change images, without a problem, but the image div ends up overlaying the div that contains the gallery name, how do I make the gallery div fixed using percentages?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/52gwc0j2/

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.photoset {
    position:relative;
    width: 52%;
    height: 69%;
}

.photoset img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(89,89,89,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
    Photoset Header
 </div>
</div> 
<div class="photoset center-block">
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-fashion-parade.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals18.jpg" />
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-in-fashion.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals20.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rac said, the height of `.photoset` is 0 because its children are absolutely positioned.

To get around this with the minimal amount of code change, update your selector from `.photoset img` to `.photoset img + img`. This will only target images placed *after* an image. What this results in is your first image sets the height of `.photoset`, and all subsequent images are overlaid on top.

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.photoset {
    position:relative;
    width: 52%;
    height: 69%;
}

.photoset img + img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(89,89,89,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
    Photoset Header
 </div>
</div> 
<div class="photoset center-block">
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-fashion-parade.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals18.jpg" />
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-in-fashion.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals20.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: @jprezov tried this and it occurs the same problem as if I changed the `.img {position: relative}` the next image will appear below the first image, not making a smooth transition with jquery

Comment: @n.ab you need to post the _full_ question then. Your question indicates that this is a CSS / HTML issue, not a jQuery one.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my mistake.

Comment: @n.ab no need for apologies. Update your code snippet to add the jQuery code, and you should get more appropriate answers (StackOverflow rules require that all code be posted in a question).

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is to change the photoset img position property to relative:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.photoset').each(function(){
    $(this).data('counter', 0);
  });

  var showCurrent = function (photoset) {
    $items = photoset.find('img');
    var counter = photoset.data('counter');
    var numItems = $items.length;
    var itemToShow = Math.abs(counter % numItems);
    var width = $(window).width;

    $items.fadeOut(1000);

    //Adjust orientation - Portrait or Landscape
    if (($items.eq(itemToShow).width() / $items.eq(itemToShow).height()) > 1) {

      photoset.css({
        width: "52%",
        height: "69%"
      });
    } else if (($items.eq(itemToShow).width() / $items.eq(itemToShow).height()) < 1) {
      photoset.css({
        width: "23%",
        height: "69%"
      });
    }
    $items.eq(itemToShow).fadeIn(1000);
  };

  $('.photoset').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var photoset = $(this);
    var pWidth = photoset.innerWidth();
    var pOffset = photoset.offset();
    var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
    if (pWidth / 2 > x) {
      photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('counter') - 1);
      showCurrent(photoset);
    } else {
      photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('counter') + 1);
      showCurrent(photoset);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.photoset {
  position:relative;
  width: 52%;
  height: 69%;
}

.photoset img {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(89,89,89,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
        Photoset Header
    </div>
</div>
<div class="photoset center-block">
    <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-fashion-parade.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals18.jpg" />
    <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-in-fashion.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals20.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, without the `position: absolute` the images won't overlap, and the next image will appear below the image that is apperaing first, not making a smooth transiction with jquery

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, using `absolute` positioning for you images is pointless - it will make things much harder. However, you can make use of the fact that `absolute` elements can be placed *behind* other elements without pushing the contents. My proposal is to simply have one single class that will tell which image you are currently displaying. The displayed image will have a `relative` position and the others will have an `absolute` position, allowing the images to appear in the same top-left hand corner, but for some to be obscured and others to be visible.

The main advantage of the approach below is that your images scale your box is you want to, and the `photoset` can be placed inline, in the document flow, as an overlay, etc... It's very versatile so give it a try. This also means that your javascript becomes lighter and easier as all you need to do is add the right class to the image to display it. You can also still add a relative box with a title in in, and it will work just fine.

```js
// Don't worry about this, its just a quick implementation to make your photos rotate
var ps = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.photoset')).forEach(function(set){
  var all = Array.prototype.slice.call(set.querySelectorAll('img'));
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    all[index].className = '';
    index = index + 1 >= all.length ? 0 : index + 1;
    all[index].className = 'active';
  },1000)
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.photoset {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(89,89,89,1);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

#absolute-photoset {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.photoset img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}

.photoset img.active {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="photoset" id="absolute-photoset">
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-fashion-parade.jpg" class="active" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals18.jpg" />
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-in-fashion.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals20.jpg" />
</div>

<h1>My Title</h1>
<div class="photoset" id="inline-photoset">
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-fashion-parade.jpg" class="active" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals18.jpg" />
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-in-fashion.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals20.jpg" />
</div>
<p>The above photoset seems to be pushing this text down as expected!</p>
```

This photoset class also pushed contents out of it's way if it is *not* positioned absolute, which I guess is what you are looking for. You can also resize the `.photoset` and the image inside should follow (I am unsure if the `max-width` will change the proportions of the image, if so, use only one-directional `max` values, like *just* `max-width`).

The main advantage is that you can treat the `.photoset` as a box and not worry about its contents, so now you can use it inline, absolutely positioned, fixed, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a height for your photoset use `padding-bottom: 50%;` and mess with the percentage until you get the height you want.  Then set the image to have a height of 100% and a width of 100% instead of top, left, right, bottom.

here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/5bgn05t1/)